# Matlab copy constructor

Tags: matlab, oop, copy-constructor

Is there a better way to implement copy construcor for matlab for a handle derived class other than adding a constructor with one input and explicitly copying its properties?

```
obj.property1 = from.property1;  
obj.property2 = from.property2;
```

etc.

Thanks,
Dani

Comment: can you elaborate?  What version of Matlab are you using?

Comment: I'm using Matlab 2008a and I use classes mostly by reference (thus deriving from handle) but I sometimes need to pass them by value, e.g.

    classdef Request < handle
         properties
            price
            quantity
        end
    end

Comment: classdef RequestManager < handle  
    properties  
        requestsHistory  
    end  
    methods  
        function HandleRequest(this, request)  
            this.requestsHistory = [this.requestsHistory request];  
        end  
    end  
end

Comment: ok. I don't have an answer yet but will post one if I think of anything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want a quick-and-dirty solution that assumes all properties can be copied, take a look at the PROPERTIES function.  Here's an example of a class that automatically copies all properties:

```
classdef Foo < handle
  properties
    a = 1;
  end
  methods
    function F=Foo(rhs)
      if nargin==0
        % default constructor
        F.a = rand(1);
      else
        % copy constructor
        fns = properties(rhs);
        for i=1:length(fns)
          F.(fns{i}) = rhs.(fns{i});
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and some test code:

```
f = Foo(); [f.a Foo(f).a] % should print 2 floats with the same value.
```

Comment: In the constructor, you should probably test that "rhs" is of type Foo (isa(rhs, 'Foo')) before starting to copy properties.

Answer (score 11):

There is another easy way to create copies of handle objects by using matlab.mixin.Copyable. If you inherit from this class you will get a copy method which will copy all the properties for you.

```
classdef YourClass < matlab.mixin.Copyable
...

a = YourClass;
b = copy(a); % b is a copy of a
```

This copy method creates a copy without calling constructors or set functions of properties. So this should be faster. You can also customize the copy behavior by overriding some methods.

Comment: What if you want to copy a subclass, i.e if a is an instance of some subclass of YourClass, but you want b NOT to be a subclass (ie. you want the super-class (YourClass) functionality)?

Comment: You would need to write your method to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You can even use

```
try
 F.(fns{i}) = rhs.(fns{i});
end
```

which makes the method more useful