# Matlab: Convert superclass to subclass object

Tags: oop, matlab, inheritance, casting

I want to create a subclass, `ess` say, to the built-in `ss` class. I'd like to be able to convert an existing `ss` object to an `ess` object and at the same time add the missing properties, e.g. `w`, by something like this

```
sys=ss(a,b,c,d);
esys=ess(sys,w);
```

but I can't figure out how to setup the constructor correctly. What is the best way to achieve this? My code currently looks like this

```
classdef ess < ss
    properties
        w
    end
    methods
        function obj = ess(varargin)
            if nargin>0 && isa(varargin{1},'StateSpaceModel')
                super_args{1} = sys;
            else
                super_args = varargin;
            end
            obj = obj@ss(super_args{:});
        end
    end 
end
```

But this does not work as I get the following error:

```
 >> ess(ss(a,b,c,d))
 ??? When constructing an instance of class 'ess', the constructor must preserve
 the class of the returned object.
```

Of course I could copy all the object properties by hand but it seems to me that there should be some better way.

Comment: Instead of writing that in the constructor, have a helper function that takes an `ss` instance and returns a new `ess` instance from that

Comment: I'm not sure that comment helps me. How should I do that? Let me try to be a little clearer: I'd like to be able to take an existing `ss` instance and add the additional information (e.g. values for `w`). Is that possible without copying all the values from the original object by hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of what I had in mind:

```
classdef ss < handle
    properties
        a
        b
    end

    methods
        function obj = ss(varargin)
            args = {0 0};     %# default values
            if nargin > 0, args = varargin; end
            obj.a = args{1};
            obj.b = args{2};
        end
    end
end
```

and:

```
classdef ess < ss
    properties
        c
    end

    methods
        function obj = ess(c, varargin)
            args = {};
            if nargin>1 && isa(varargin{1}, 'ss')
                args = getProps(varargin{1});
            end
            obj@ss(args{:});    %# call base-class constructor
            obj.c = c;
        end     
    end
end

%# private function that extracts object properties
function props = getProps(ssObj)
    props{1} = ssObj.a;
    props{2} = ssObj.b;
end
```

Lets test those classes:

```
x = ss(1,2);
xx = ess(3,x)
```

I get:

```
xx = 
  ess handle

  Properties:
    c: 3
    a: 1
    b: 2
  Methods, Events, Superclasses
```

Comment: If you want to make the above function `getProps` more generic, you could use reflection to extract the object properties without hard-coding their names. Something like: `m = metaclass(ssObj);` then loop over the properties to extract the values `ssObj.(m.PropertyList(i).Name)`

Comment: Okay, that's what I meant by "copying properties by hand". I guess that's the way to go then. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Great, thanks for the additional pointer. It should be something like `x.(m.Properties{i}.Name)` I guess, right?

Comment: @sebhofer: here is [another example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/247430/97160) that implements a copy-constructor like behavior. You should also look into [`matlab.mixin.Copyable`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/matlab.mixin.copyableclass.html), although I haven't used it before...