# How to make a deep copy of object in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have an object, which is a matlab class. I want to copy a few members of the class to other variables, but matlab is copying the reference and not the value.

The class definition is `classdef MyObj < handle`, and I have a member `A` where `A` is iteself a struct. So, `A` looks like this:

```
A.num1
A.num2
A.num3
```

So, I create `A`: `A = MyObj`, then assign some values: `A.num1=1`, `A.num2=2`, and `A.num3=3`. Now, I want to copy members of `A` to another variable. For example, `c(1)=A.num1`, then I want to modify `A`, and copy the element to another variable `c(2)=A.num1`, etc... However, the copy is a reference, so I end up with all variable `c(1), c(2), etc...` all equal to the same value.

This is an example to illustrate my question. The object I am working with has much more complex structs. How can I make a deep copy?

Comment: You may inherit your class from [matlab.mixin.Copyable](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.mixin.copyable-class.html). and use 
`B = copy(A)`. Check the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247430/matlab-copy-constructor).

Comment: Or you could not inherit from `handle`, then all assignments create copies.